Tensorflow Federated Installation Error M3 Max
I tried to install Tensorflow-Federated however, I always receive errors.
To provide some context:
I tested installing the library using a venv using python 3.10 & 3.12. Both times the errors are the same.
Virtual environment is created like so:
python3 -m venv venv.
No additional libraries are installed.
Error:

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.34.0 Requires-Python ~=3.9.0; 0.36.0 Requires-Python ~=3.9.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-federated==0.87.0 (from versions: 0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.19.0, 0.20.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 0.29.0, 0.30.0, 0.31.0, 0.32.0, 0.33.0, 0.37.0, 0.38.0, 0.39.0, 0.40.0, 0.41.0, 0.42.0, 0.43.0, 0.44.0, 0.45.0, 0.46.0, 0.47.0, 0.48.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-federated==0.87.0
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 24.2.
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip

Using this command
pip install --quiet --upgrade tensorflow-federated.
I get this error:

error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "/private/var/folders/_5/43xzfz3s7s39pd__1mjxhghs8mhgqx/T/pip-install-rf1_8hkm/absl-py_60c286cd5b39445b923d58027d7ce51c/setup.py",
line 34, in 
raise RuntimeError('Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.')
RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or 3.4+ is required.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
× Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
for output.
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

There is no other library installed in the venv, it's clean.
Python version is verified by using python --version.
I have a hard time finding any requirements as to which python versions are supported or what to do. I verified that the python version active is 3.10 or 3.12, which confuses me because the error message clearly states I have to use python greater than 3.4+ or at least 2.7. I have never used python2 in my life and there is only 3.10 and 3.12 installed on my laptop.
I used this tutorial to no avail:
https://github.com/google-parfait/tensorflow-federated/blob/main/docs/install.md
Could someone point me in the right direction, please?
